# Factory girl is creating some strange resource entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, guard

**spec helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "example@hotmail.com"
        password "password"
    end
end
```

**###_create.rb**

```
class Create < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**password_resets_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
    it "emails user when requesting a password rest" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        visit "/users"
    end
end
```

Okay, so there is my spec helper, my factory, my database migration to create User instances and, most importantly, password_resets_spec.rb

Upon running it I'd expect a user instance to be created in the test User table:

```
id | email | password | created_at | updated_at

1 | example@hotmail.com | password | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
```

For capybara to browse to an existing route, and for no failures to be incurred.

I run once it once, and this though I get no failures, rspec has gone through 23 examples. This is what happens in my table:

```
    id | email | password | created_at | updated_at

    1 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    2 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    3 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    4 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    5 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    6 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    7 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    8 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
    9 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
   10 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
   11 | MyString |    | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 | 2013-12-13 04-32-12 |
```

I run the same test a second time and I get this failure

```
UsersController GET index assigns all users as @users
```

The table is now twice as big, with 23 identical 'MyString' entries. What on earth is going on?

If I get rid of the

```
visit "/users"
```

it all works as expected. Everything. So what's capybara doing? Why would it create 11 "MyString" entries? Where's "MyString" even coming from? So weird.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some basic debugging here. Try printing out the contents of the users table after FactoryGirl's create, and after the visit. Ensure that it is, in fact, factory girl that's doing something wrong, and not your code.

Comment: It looks like no records are cleaned (deleted) after tests. Maybe [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) will help you

Comment: Good suggestion but it's a really weird error. Always 11 entries, without fail. So odd.